# Typescript Angular Cannot find name

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working on Aspnet Core Angular project and getting following error:

> ```
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'email'.
> ```

The code is executed in visual studio 2017.

```
postEmailValidate(email?: string): Observable<any> {
    var data: {
        "Email": email,
        "Timeout": "5",
        "Verbose": "True"
    };        
    return this.http.post(
        this.urlEmailValidate,
        data,
        { headers: this.getHeaders("POST") }
        )
        //.delay(5000)
        .map(this.handleSuccess)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

The code is very basic and I have declared a variable in the function's call.
But the compiler gives the following error. Am I forgetting something or is it a visual studio issue.

[image]

[image]